# How to estimate sample size needed for a planned comparison between two groups in a between-within ANOVA?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, statistical-power, gpower

I have a 3X3 repeated measures ANOVA with 3 groups and 3 measurement timepoints. In addition to the omnibus effect, I am interested in comparing the difference in change within two timepoints between two groups. How should I calculate the sample size I need to sufficiently power that follow-up test in G*Power? Would it be reasonable to use the settings below and simply add another 74 participants to account for the third group?

[image]